# GeoTools, Java: How to convert shapefile data from DOR to usable polygons with Latitude and Longitude coordinates

Tags: java, gis, projection, geotools, spc

The shapefiles I'm concerned with can be found here, though I'm sure this could apply to any shapefile using coordinates based on state plane coordinates:

http://dor.wa.gov/content/FindTaxesAndRates/stshpdownloads.aspx

I'm currently using GeoTools, a java toolkit designed for reading in GIS shapefiles like these and displaying information about them. I am able to iterate through the file and display the polygons associated with each tax jurisdiction, but here's an example line of output:

```
Seattle|0.096|MULTIPOLYGON(((1157963.4622609913 862693.0463841558, 
1157982.575083658 862880.4607074857, 1158623.4100880772 
864826.6100303978, ... )))
```

Based on my research, these coordinates don't seem to line up with any of the typical coordinate systems. I'm expecting that they are derived from a coordinate system known as State Plane Coordinates, but currently don't seem to be in the right format even for those. I was hoping someone might know where these values come from and if there is a way to get GeoTools to output them in a more standardized Latitude/Longitude format.

Comment: If I rember it right, shapefiles store the projection with them. If you can get the projection from the file or the projection's `EPSG`-code (a global identifier for projections), you automatically know how to process the coordinates.

Comment: Look at the crs tutorial on geotools.org and you will see how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded the most recent shapefile from the site and put them into ArcGIS and it says the following:

```
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile:  C:\Users\(...)\Downloads\Cities_17Q3\Cities_17Q3.shp
Geometry Type:  Polygon
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No 

Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Washington_South_FIPS_4602_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  1640416,66666667
False_Northing: 0,00000000
Central_Meridian:   -120,50000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    45,83333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    47,33333333
Latitude_Of_Origin: 45,33333333
Linear Unit:    Foot_US

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983_HARN
Datum:  D_North_American_1983_HARN
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Also, the polygon for seattle seems to visually line up:

[image]

This means that you are using the `GCS_North_American_1983_HARN` coordinate system with the `Lambert_Conformal_Conic` projection